# Groovy/Grails: Fill up String Placeholder with current instance

Tags: string, grails, groovy

Im really new to groovy/grails and I want to implement following:

In Groovy.config declare a string with a placeholder:

```
urls.sampleUrl = "http://foo/bar/${person.name}.jpg"
```

Later in another file, I want to fill up the placeholder with the current instance of the 'person'-object:

```
private void updateUrls(Person person)
{
      def sampleString = urls.sampleUrl;
}
```

sampleString should then be, for example: _http://foo/bar/anthony.jpg
But the output is:  _http://foo/bar/[:].jpg

How could I solve this?

...of course the code is probably wrong, I know, but its just for make you understanding my problem ;-)

Thanks for help.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
urls.sampleUrl = "http://foo/bar/${->person.name}.jpg"
```

this will turn it into a GString. The closure will be executed when the .toString() is applied.

example:

```
def person = [name: 'jim']
def sampleUrl = "http://foo/bar/${->person.name}.jpg"
println person.name
println sampleUrl
person.name = 'jeff'
println sampleUrl
```

it could be that you run into a problem with

- the scope of person.name . It must be defined before you define the GString
- the config itself. If it is a properties file, I guess it does not know about GStrings

So you can also just use a replace like the following one:

```
def person = [name: 'jim']
def sampleUrl = "http://foo/bar/{0}.jpg"
println person.name
println sampleUrl.replace('{0}',person.name)
person.name = 'jeff'
println sampleUrl.replace('{0}',person.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I'll try it with replacing ;-)